# Python Regex: Trying to create pattern

Tags: python, regex, string

I did my best to check the internet and stack for info but I am having trouble wrapping my head around regex for my utility.

I have a string that follows this pattern:

```
[any a-z,1-9]_reel[0-9]*2_scn[0-9]*4_shot[0-9]*4
```

**ex:**

```
kim_reel05_scn0101_shot0770

n74_reel05_scn0001_shot0700

ninehundred_reel05_scn0001_shot0700
```

I need to check those examples to see if it follows that proj_reel##_scn####_shot#### pattern and then if it does proceed!
I am not sure how to write this expression as I honestly am having trouble understanding how to use the special characters.

someone want to help me out?

Comment: something like `prog_reel[0-9]{2}_scn[0-9]{4}_shot{0-9]{4}` ?

Comment: You can change `[0-9]` to `\d`.

Comment: thanks let me give that a go!

Comment: Did you also read the manual? Because, for python regex module, this is a better starting point than "the internet".

Comment: @Sebastian I did and it start off great but then it got into some some stuff I didn't understand and I lost how I could use it lol

Comment: Why go through the trouble to validate and fail if the exact amount of digits are not present when the static text (`_reel,_scn,_shot`) are your anchors ? Ever hear of false negatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^proj_reel[0-9]{2}_scn[0-9]{4}_shot[0-9]{4}$
```

You can try this.Do not forget to set`g` and `m` flags.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/35

Answer (score 0):

You can use **re.match** to test if a string matches your search pattern, if not it returns None.

```
import re

test = ['kim_reel05_scn0101_shot0770',
        'n74_reel05_scn0001_shot0700',
        'ninehundred_reel05_scn0001_shot0700',
        'proj_reel05_scn0001_shot0700',
        'n74_reel05_scn0001_shot0700',
        'ninehundred_reel05_scn0001_shot0700']


valid = re.compile(r'\bproj_reel[\d]{2}_scn[\d]{4}_shot[\d]{4}\b')

for t in test:
    if re.match(valid, t):
        #proceed
        print('Valid:', t)
    else:
        print('Invalid:', t)
```

output:

```
Invalid: kim_reel05_scn0101_shot0770
Invalid: n74_reel05_scn0001_shot0700
Invalid: ninehundred_reel05_scn0001_shot0700
Valid: proj_reel05_scn0001_shot0700
Invalid: n74_reel05_scn0001_shot0700
Invalid: ninehundred_reel05_scn0001_shot0700
```